# Read params from a json file for protractor tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor

I've commented out the lines trying to read the files, is there a way I can retrieve the values from the files inside `protractor.config.ts` instead of having to pass as command line args?

protractor.config.ts

```
import { } from 'jasmine';
import { Config } from 'protractor';

//import fs = require('fs'); // Cannot find module 'fs'
//import param1 = require('test/e2e/param1.json'); // Cannot find module 'test/e2e/param1.json'
//import param2 = require('test/e2e/param2.json'); // Cannot find module 'test/e2e/param2.json'

export let config: Config = {
  rootElement: 'my-app',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['test/e2e/**/*.js'],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/',
  params: {
    param1: '13bf8265-06d6-45c3-97fc-0d6da7b6b597',
    param2: '14490027-e55b-4739-a5a9-5c091c5d4a72'
  }
};
```

test/e2e/param1.json:

```
{
  "param1": "13bf8265-06d6-45c3-97fc-0d6da7b6b597"
}
```

test/e2e/param2.json:

```
{
  "param2": "14490027-e55b-4739-a5a9-5c091c5d4a72"
}
```

Comment: if you mean getting the value from protractor.config.js itself, then you can use `browser.params.param1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding import statements as follows:

```
import * as file1 from './test/e2e/param1.json'
import * as file2 from './test/e2e/param2.json'
console.log(file1.param1)
```

If you're seeing an error stating: `Cannot find module 'test/e2e/param1.json'`
 then you'll need to create / update your `TypeScript` definition | declaration file, see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

Add the following to your definition | declaration file:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

After which your file imports as shown above will work perfectly.